# Extend hard disk partition by adding another hard disk

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, diskmanagement

I am running Windows Server 2012 R2.
I have C: and D: partitions at the moment.
There are two hard disks, C: is on one disk and D: is expanded on remaining space of first disk and the other disk.
Can I add another hard disk and expand D: further, without loosing any data?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can, but it usually isn't a good idea, since it increases the chance that a drive failure  will result in data lose.

Answer (score -1):

If Roles are configured on your server for the D drive then go to  Administrative Tools -> Cluster Manager -> Roles -> File-Share. On clicking  ' File Share ' some tasks will be available on the right hand side, clicked 'Add Storage '. The additional (online) disks will be visible and click the  disk u want to add to D drive and press 'OK'.  Now your D drive role is extended to the new disk also.

Comment: That only makes sense (and not much of it) for a cluster, which is not involved here.